# Find JSON index based on child key value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the below JSON which controls the flow of the pages in my application. To navigate between screens manually I use the index of a page. If I were to link to Page 1 I would use the index '0'. I would like to be able to navigate using the `id` instead. So I could use `S010_010` to navigate. Unfortunately the navigation function of the app is used by multiple elements and cannot be changed completely so I am looking for a method that can take the id and return the index from `flows`.

```
var flows = {
  "default": [{
      theme: "theme1",
      events: "touchstart",
      easingSlideIn: "transition.fadeIn",
      easingSlideOut: "transition.fadeOut",
      easingRef: "transition.perspectiveRightIn",
      easingPop: "transition.flipYIn"
    },
    {
      id: "S010_010", //0
      description: "",
      chapter: "01",
      ref: ""
    },
    {
      id: "S020_010", //1
      description: "",
      chapter: "01",
      ref: ""
    },
    {
      id: "S030_010", //2
      description: "",
      chapter: "01",
      ref: ""
    },
  ]
};
```

This is an example of how I currently retrieve the `id` using the index:

```
this.options.flow[screen +1].id
```

Comment: Something like: `flows.default.filter(o => o.id === 'S010_010')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for-in to iterate and return the index if id matches with that of method's. It is also recommended to use `for-of` but you end up descructing something like this `for(const [index, value] of flows.default.entries())` to fetch index hence used for-in

```js
let flows = {
  "default": [{
      theme: "theme1",
      events: "touchstart",
      easingSlideIn: "transition.fadeIn",
      easingSlideOut: "transition.fadeOut",
      easingRef: "transition.perspectiveRightIn",
      easingPop: "transition.flipYIn"
    },
    {
      id: "S010_010", //0
      description: "",
      chapter: "01",
      ref: ""
    },
    {
      id: "S020_010", //1
      description: "",
      chapter: "01",
      ref: ""
    },
    {
      id: "S030_010", //2
      description: "",
      chapter: "01",
      ref: ""
    },
  ]
};

let getFlowByID = (id) => {
for(let eachFlowIndex in flows.default){
 if(flows.default[eachFlowIndex].id == id){
  return eachFlowIndex;
 }
 }
}

console.log(getFlowByID("S030_010")); // gets S030_010 index
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This worked really well and thank you for the explanation. Easier to understand what is happening here. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific method, but you can create your own inverted index

```
var invertedIndex = {};
flows.default.forEach((elem, index) => {
   if(elem.id != null) {
      invertedIndex[elem.id] = index - 1;
   }
})
//then you can use the id for the lookup as
invertedIndex['S030_010']
```

Comment: I am currently getting this error: `is an instance of Array` I am pulling the flow list using `this.options.flow` as it is being used within another function. If I use console.log to show the output of `this.options.flow` I see ARRAY with the json

Comment: Can confirm this is also a valid method that functions too

Comment: The one advantage of preprocessing is that it converts an O(N) lookup to an O(1) lookup which might be useful of the dataset is large

Answer (score 0):

We use `for in` cycle to iterate through our array of objects and return the index if id was found.

**ES5 solution**

```js
var flows =
{
    "default":
    [
        {
            theme: "theme1",
            events: "touchstart",
            easingSlideIn: "transition.fadeIn",
            easingSlideOut: "transition.fadeOut",
            easingRef: "transition.perspectiveRightIn",
            easingPop: "transition.flipYIn"
        },
        {
            id: "S010_010", //0
            description: "",
            chapter: "01",
            ref: ""
        },
        {
            id: "S020_010", //1
            description: "",
            chapter: "01",
            ref: ""
        },
        {
            id: "S030_010", //2
            description: "",
            chapter: "01",
            ref: ""
        }
    ]
};

function getIndex(id)
{
    var i = 0,
        objs = flows.default;

    for (i in objs)
        if (objs[i].id == id)
            return +i - 1
}

console.log(getIndex('S010_010')); //0
```

**ES6 solution**

We use **[`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** function to iterate through our array, save the index if id was found and than return it. In the case if it is not found it returns -1. But unfortunatelly this solution isn't shorter than my ES5 solution.

```js
var flows =
{
    "default":
    [
        {
            theme: "theme1",
            events: "touchstart",
            easingSlideIn: "transition.fadeIn",
            easingSlideOut: "transition.fadeOut",
            easingRef: "transition.perspectiveRightIn",
            easingPop: "transition.flipYIn"
        },
        {
            id: "S010_010", //0
            description: "",
            chapter: "01",
            ref: ""
        },
        {
            id: "S020_010", //1
            description: "",
            chapter: "01",
            ref: ""
        },
        {
            id: "S030_010", //2
            description: "",
            chapter: "01",
            ref: ""
        }
    ]
};

let getIndex = (id) => {

    let ret = -1;
    flows.default.find((elem, index) => {
        if(elem.id == id)
            ret = index - 1
    });
    return ret
};


console.log(getIndex('S010_010')); //0
```